# After disabling Multisite, homepage redirects to non-existing page

Tags: redirect, homepage

I disabled Multisite. Deleted all wp-config lines, updated .htaccess with the default code and deleted all MySQL entries.

Now my homepage - pitch.pt - keeps redirecting to pitch.pt/home2.

All other pages, posts and dashboard are working fine.

I went on phpMyAdmin and found that on `wp_options` the URLs were set to home2, but already fixed that.

I've disabled plugins, verified wp-config and updated permalinks.

Comment: Can you search a mysqldump for home2 just to see if there are any references left to it, e.g. in transients? But I can't see why there would be.

Comment: @Rup i found 33 entries on wp_posts with the /home2.

Comment: @Rup, fixed everything on that table and it's working again!